# Julia convert seconds to integer from Dates package: no method matching Int64(::Second)

Tags: datetime, julia

I'm using the Dates module and I'm trying to convert a Seconds object to an integer.

When I try the following, I get an error:

```
x = Second(5)
Int(x)
# ERROR: MethodError: no method matching Int64(::Second)
```

Why doesn't this work? How do I just extract this as a integer value?

My question also applies to converting minutes to integer, days to integer, months to integer, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand on the answer from J. Blauvelt, the omission of `convert(Int, d)` is deliberate. The reason is that `convert` often implies equivalence, and is used *automatically* when adding elements to containers:

```
julia> c = [1,2]
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2

julia> push!(c, Second(5))
ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Second to an object of type Int64
Closest candidates are:
  convert(::Type{T<:Number}, ::T<:Number) where T<:Number at number.jl:6
  convert(::Type{T<:Number}, ::Number) where T<:Number at number.jl:7
  convert(::Type{T<:Integer}, ::Ptr) where T<:Integer at pointer.jl:23
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] push!(::Array{Int64,1}, ::Second) at ./array.jl:853
 [2] top-level scope at none:0
```

If you allowed this kind of automatic conversion, you could get quite confused: for example, `push!(c, Day(5))` would also put `5` into `c`, and suddenly you're in a situation where you've implied that `Day(5) == Second(5)`.

Now, constructor syntax `Int(t)` is not the same as `convert(Int, t)`. So in principle, perhaps this could be allowed. But historically the two were intertwined, and there may be a fair amount of code that doesn't distinguish the two.

Consequently, when you're asking for something related to the *internal* representation, for now it seems better to require the user to exploit that representation directly (e.g., `t = Second(5); t.value`). Or, write your code in a way that allows you to keep these values along with their units.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using an Int constructor, access the .value property of the Second object:

```
x = Second(5)
x.value # 5
```

This works for the other objects from the Dates module such as `Minute`, `Day`, `Month`, etc.

Check out @tholy's answer too for a great explanation of why it's structured like this.

As a side note, `dump()` is a helpful function in situations like this - when you're working with an unfamiliar object and you want to understand how to access its attributes and so forth:

```
dump(x)
# Output:
# Second
#  value: Int64 5
```